# Tomcat7 Alternative

Tags: java, web-applications, webserver

I have never used something different than tomcat. For my current university project I programmed a WebApplication with JSF and Java EE 6. I have to hand it in installed on a VM with Ubuntu OS.

My fellow student told me that Tomcat7 is not released for Ubuntu (or is it?) and tomcat 6 doesn't provide Java EE 6 capabilities.

So I want to ask you if there is an appropriate alternative? Maybe something that doesn't have to require a lot of induction for a tomcat user.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Why in this world you need Ubuntu! inside VM!, including all that device-detection and desktop-friendly stuff taking a loads of time to start up!?

Comment: All well designed Java applications runs everywhere where a JRE/JVM is installed. JRE/JVM is available for different platforms, including Ububtu. Java applications are not platform-specific per se. That's one of the ideologies behind *Java*! Note that Tomcat doesn't implement the full JEE6 stack, only the Servlet/JSP parts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think Tomcat is release *for* anything.

They just put out **a** release, and V7.0 (I think as of 7.0.6) has now been declared production ready.

So just create your VM with Ubuntu, install Java, download Tomcat, unzip the bundle and install your application.

Comment: This. There doesn't need to be a Tomcat 7 installer or package to use it. It should run on any OS with Java.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with [Jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/), which damn fast and light.

But it does not support Java EE natively.

What are good alternatives? [Glassfish](http://glassfish.java.net/)/[JBoss](http://jboss.org/jbossas/).

Answer (score 0):

try the new Jboss, it`s really easy to use, almost the same from tomcat, and they should have for ubuntu( the new version) because they are from red hat too!

EDIT:
To clarify my statement before,  Jboss it`s as easy as tomcat to deploy a simple J2EE app.

Comment: check this: http://www.jboss.org/overview/mainColumnParagraphs/0/2columnLeftParagraphs/03/2columnLeftParagraphs/0/image/homepagespotlight_300x215_AS6.png

Comment: Jboss became easy to use? Now, that's a major change of strategy for redhat.

Answer (score 0):

[Glassfish](http://glassfish.java.net/) is a well-known free open-source Java application server, but it's a bit more full featured than Tomcat and thus potentially more complicated (it has a full Java EE stack).

[Jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/) is more like Tomcat in that it's primarily a servlet container, you can take a look at that as well.  Some projects (such as Grails) have switched from using Jetty to Tomcat for various reasons, but it may work for your needs.